# How to deal with GSutil URI not working all the time

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, path, gsutil, errno

I am facing a little issue here that I can't explain.

On some occasions, I am able to open files from my cloud storage buckets using a GSutil URI. For instance this one works fine

```
df = pd.read_csv('gs://poker030120203/ouptut_test.csv')
```

But on some other occasions, this method does not work & returns an error  `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

This happens for instance with the following codes

```
rank_table_filename = 'gs://poker030120203/rank_table.bin'
rank_table_file = open(rank_table_filename, "r")
```

```
preflop_table_filename = 'gs://poker030120203/preflop_table.npy'
self.preflop_table = np.load(preflop_table_filename)
```

I am not sure if this is related to the "open" or "load" methode, or maybe the file type, but I can't figure out why this return an error. I do not know if this has an impact on that matter, but I'm running everything from Vertex (ie. the AI module that automatically sets up a storage bucket / a VM and a jupyter notebook).

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Hi @Raphaël Ambit's, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 0):

In order to  read and write the file from the google cloud storage, you can use google [recommended methods](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to). It's easier to use google client libraries to read / write anything from / in Google Cloud Storage.

**From the doc Example:**

```
from google.cloud import storage


def write_read(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Write and read a blob from GCS using file-like IO"""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    # The ID of your new GCS object
    # blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    # Mode can be specified as wb/rb for bytes mode.
    # See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html
    with blob.open("w") as f:
        f.write("Hello world")

    with blob.open("r") as f:
        print(f.read())
```

Comment: Of course I read it but was not able to properly use it. Especially as most of GCP doc focus on call blob, which does not workwith .bin files

Comment: @RaphaëlAmbit I have opened a bin format file using the above code. To open and read a `bin format` file you have to use `rb` instead of `r` in the `with` statement example: with blob.open("rb") as f. Can you share the error message you are facing when opening the bin format file using blob?